# how to find n nearest tuples to a particular cell in matlab

Tags: matlab, mean

```
a=size(t,1)
b=size(t,2)
 for j=1:b
    for i=1:a
        if t(i,j)=='yes'
            t(i,j)=mode(t(:,j))
        elseif t(i,j)=='no'
            t(i,j)=mode(t(:,j))  
        elseif t(i,j)==0
            t(i,j)=mean(t((i+1):(i+k),j))
            end
          end
        end
    end
 end
```

How can we calculate the mean of four adjacent neighbours of a number (two numbers selected from immediate left and  immediate right of the number) instead of finding the mean of four elements which are immediate right of the number in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you refer to the following part of the code that you posted:

```
t(i,j)=mean(t((i+1):(i+k),j))
```

What this line does, is to take the mean of the values `t(i+1, j), t(i+2, j) , ..., t(i+k,j)`.

If you wanted to take the mean of upper and lower rows instead, you could do sth like (assuming that `k` is an even number like four):

```
t(i,j)=mean([t((i-k/2):(i-1),j), t((i+1):(i+k/2),j)])
```

instead. However, this would overwrite entries of `t` that are later used when taking the average of other values, so you would have to make a copy of `t` first:

```
 t_copy = t
 a=size(t,1)
 b=size(t,2)
 for j=1:b
    for i=1:a
        ...
        t(i,j)=mean([t_copy((i-k/2):(i-1),j), t_copy((i+1):(i+k/2),j)])
    end
 end
```